# Is there a way to mod a number so that it's in the range between -1 and 1?

Tags: python

Let's say I have numbers such as these

- 1.7
- 1.2
- 0.2
- -0.3
- -1.2

Is there a formula that i can apply to these numbers such that I get

- -0.3
- -0.8
- 0.2
- -0.3
- 0.8

Basically I want the number so that if it's above 1 it'll loop around starting at -1...so that my number will always be in the range of [-1,1]
and if the number is below -1 it'll wrap around starting at 1.

Comment: I'm sure there's more than one function that could output everything in the range -1 to 1. Scaled versions `sin` and `cos` quickly come to mind. What's the range of numbers used as input and how even does the distribution of them need to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subtract 1, then mod 2, then subtract 1.

```
>>> seq = [1.7, 1.2, 0.2, -0.3, -1.2]
>>> [(x-1) % 2 - 1 for x in seq]
[-0.30000000000000004, -0.8, 0.19999999999999996, -0.30000000000000004, 0.7999999999999998]
```

Although it looks like there is a small loss of precision due to floating point arithmetic. You could `round` if you only care about a set number of digits after the decimal point.

```
>>> [round((x-1) % 2 - 1, 1) for x in seq]
[-0.3, -0.8, 0.2, -0.3, 0.8]
```

Comment: If done right, there should be no precision loss at all: the reduction is always exactly representable.

Comment: Thanks...this is great.
I noticed if If I add 1, then mod 2, then subtract 1.  Seems to produce the same output but easier for me to visualize.

Comment: I suppose adding works too. IIRC, x+1 mod 2 == x-1 mod 2 for any x.

Comment: Excellent I'll add then, because it's easier for me to visualize, but i wouldn't have come up with that it wasn't for your answer...thanks again

Comment: I don't get why you're subtracting _or_ adding 1. `x % 2` is always going to output in the range `(0, 2]`. You can't divide anything by 2 and have less than 0 or more than 2 remaining. Shifting the input by 1 in either direction changes the answer to the modulo, but not the range of the modulo function. The subtraction at the end is all that's needed to shift the `(0, 2]` range down to the desired `(-1, 1]` (though do note that -1 is possible and not +1 still).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, I agree that performing subtraction/addition before the modulus is not strictly necessary, since the result would still be between -1 and 1 anyway. But it wouldn't exactly match the expected output given in the OP. For instance, `1.7 % 2 - 1` would become 0.7 rather than the desired -0.3